# Let's encrypt / Certbot error Google App Engine: URL 404 Not Found + non-zero code: 100

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, lets-encrypt

I'm  implementing encryption on  my website. It's hosted on Google Appengine using PHP as the backend language. I'm using  Let's encrypt for the encryption. My assumption is that  Google Appengine is using a LAMP to  make the website. I also assume that the  type of  Linux is Ubuntu. These assumptions are the basis on why I choose those options  on [this](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-apache) webpage. This leads me to  believe that I should  execute the following  commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache 
$ sudo certbot --apache
$ sudo certbot -a dns-plugin -i apache -d "*.example.com" -d example.com --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
$ sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

These commands  can't be  entered into the Google Cloud Bash though. I  enter them into a dockerfile which  looks like this:

```
FROM gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell:latest

# Add your content here
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python-certbot-apache
RUN certbot --apache
RUN certbot -a dns-google -i apache -d "*.danieljohndunevant.io" -d danieljohndunevant.io --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
RUN certbot renew --dry-run
# To trigger a rebuild of your Cloud Shell image:

# 1. Commit your changes locally: git commit -a
# 2. Push your changes upstream: git push origin master

# This triggers a rebuild of your image hosted at https://gcr.io/bold-origin-211113/djdioo
# You can find the Cloud Source Repository hosting this file at https://source.developers.google.com/p/bold-origin-211113/r/djdioo
```

The tutorial for how to set up a docker file gives you the following command to execute in order to debug image that you're creating:

```
cloudshell env build-local
```

The full output when I execute the command is the  following:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  50.18kB
Step 1/9 : FROM gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell:latest
 ---> 15c050b71ac4
Step 2/9 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 119e813f8183
Hit:1 http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease [166 kB]
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:6 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-stretch InRelease
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease [91.8 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Hit:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release
Get:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease [39.5 kB]
Hit:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Get:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch InRelease [2852 B]
Get:13 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main Sources [181 kB]
Get:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources.diff/Index [27.8 kB]
Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index [27.8 kB]
Get:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-19-0221.46.pdiff [5029 B]
Get:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-19-2029.26.pdiff [923 B]
Get:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-20-0220.22.pdiff [243 B]
Get:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-20-1412.59.pdiff [853 B]
Get:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-20-2016.48.pdiff [6000 B]
Get:21 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-21-0211.44.pdiff [847 B]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-21-1411.16.pdiff [241 B]
Get:23 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-22-1416.48.pdiff [956 B]
Get:24 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-22-2010.06.pdiff [1531 B]
Get:25 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-23-0213.38.pdiff [882 B]
Get:26 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [452 kB]
Get:27 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-23-0807.47.pdiff [33 B]
Get:28 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-23-1412.59.pdiff [13.4 kB]
Get:29 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-23-2006.55.pdiff [2376 B]
Get:30 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-24-0212.43.pdiff [87 B]
Get:31 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-24-0807.15.pdiff [1087 B]
Get:32 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-24-1407.53.pdiff [33 B]
Get:33 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-18-2018.05.pdiff [1572 B]
Get:34 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-19-0812.57.pdiff [1684 B]
Get:32 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main Sources 2018-10-24-1407.53.pdiff [33 B]
Get:36 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-19-1413.02.pdiff [20.3 kB]
Get:37 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-20-0220.22.pdiff [1770 B]
Get:39 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch/main amd64 Packages [28.7 kB]
Get:40 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main Sources.diff/Index [5656 B]
Get:41 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages [4783 B]
Get:42 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index [5656 B]
Get:43 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-20-2016.48.pdiff [1319 B]
Get:44 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-21-0211.44.pdiff [4166 B]
Get:45 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-21-0807.48.pdiff [521 B]
Get:46 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-21-1411.16.pdiff [270 B]
Get:47 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-22-0209.19.pdiff [1657 B]
Get:48 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-22-2010.06.pdiff [810 B]
Get:49 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-23-0213.38.pdiff [2897 B]
Get:50 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-23-0807.47.pdiff [456 B]
Get:51 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-23-1412.59.pdiff [11.3 kB]
Get:52 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-24-0212.43.pdiff [2666 B]
Get:53 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-24-0807.15.pdiff [624 B]
Get:54 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-24-1407.53.pdiff [216 B]
Get:54 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-24-1407.53.pdiff [216 B]
Get:55 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main Sources 2018-10-20-2016.48.pdiff [792 B]
Get:56 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-20-2016.48.pdiff [1577 B]
Get:55 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main Sources 2018-10-20-2016.48.pdiff [792 B]
Get:56 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages 2018-10-20-2016.48.pdiff [1577 B]
Fetched 1308 kB in 2s (479 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
 ---> d918ded6e546
Removing intermediate container 119e813f8183
Step 3/9 : RUN apt-get install software-properties-common
 ---> Running in 855a7668814a
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.96.20.2-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgoogle-perftools4 libtcmalloc-minimal4
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
 ---> dd6e99aae634
Removing intermediate container 855a7668814a
Step 4/9 : RUN add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
 ---> Running in 66578e8dac00
 This is the PPA for packages prepared by Debian Let's Encrypt Team and backported for Ubuntu(s).
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~certbot/+archive/ubuntu/certbot
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp5au8x0v1/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmp5au8x0v1/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 8C47BE8E75BCA694: public key "Launchpad PPA for certbot" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 480, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 438, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 436, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'
 ---> f0b11dadc6de
Removing intermediate container 66578e8dac00
Step 5/9 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in f913cd006561
Hit:1 http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release
Hit:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Hit:10 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-stretch InRelease
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic InRelea
se
Hit:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-
prod stretch InRelease
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic Release
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main am
d64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main al
l Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main am
d64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main al
l Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main am
d64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main al
l Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main am
d64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main al
l Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main am
d64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main al
l Packages
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main am
d64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu cosmic/main al
l Packages
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu co
smic Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/di
sts/cosmic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or ol
d ones used instead.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I near the  end of the  output you can see the 404 error and the error code: 100. Thanks for reading. Hope one of you  can come up with a  solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google do provide the managed SSL solution using Let's Encrypt with auto-renewal.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#managed-certs

What was the reason that you have to manage this on your own?

Comment: Thanks! I think this will be a lot more simple!